# Why does this object periodically turn itself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, stability

See below gif image taken from [here](http://sploid.gizmodo.com/space-makes-things-that-are-spinning-act-completely-cra-1725334216).

[image]

Or see [this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dL6Pt1O_gSE) about 30 sec in.

1. Is this a real effect?
2. Why does it seem to turn periodically?
3. Can it be explained by classical mechanics alone?
4. Is there a simple equation that models this behaviour?

Comment: Related post [Dzhanibekov Effect on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81960/dzhanibekov-effect-exercise-on-mechanics-or-a-fiction-explain-this-http)

Comment: L. D. LANDAU and E. M. LIFSHITZ, "MECHANICS": The asymmetrical top

Comment: [The answer!](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67957/)

Comment: [Veritasium video with Terence Tao's MO explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VPfZ_XzisU).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It's a classical mechanics effect for sure although a really interesting one. Following links on "Dzhanibekov effect" one gets at Marsden and Ratiu's ["Introduction to Mechanics and Symmetry"](http://books.google.com/books?id=I2gH9ZIs-3AC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) Chapter 15 Section 15.9 "Rigid Body Stability" treating this with use of the Casimir functions.

From remark 1: *A rigid body tossed about its middle axis will undergo an interesting half twist when the opposite saddle point is reached*.

Here is another and more profound example under weightless conditions.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2o9eBl_Gzw

This seems to be a home experiment where a guy throws the spinning object upwards.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VwS5ykAUHI

And this seems to be a computer simulation.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LR5hkgfRPno

There is a related unstable orbit effect which you can try out easily yourself with a tennis racket. A treatment due to Ashbauch Chicone and Cushman is here:

Mark S. Ashbaugh, Carmen C. Chicone and Richard H. Cushman, The Twisting Tennis Racket, Journal of Dynamics and Differential Equations, Volume 3, Number 1, 67-85 (1991). (One time found at <s>http://math.ucalgary.ca/files/publications/cushman/tennis.pdf</s> which is no longer a working link.)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dqCQqI-Gis

Comment: This seems more like a list of references than an answer. It would be nice to have the important points explained here.