# What is centre of rotation and a ref. point fixed wrt to the body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

I'm studying Analytical Mechanics, and in the section about the kinematics of rigid body, it is mentioned the following concepts:

> 1. Center of rotation
> 2. a reference position that is fixed with respect to the body

**Question 1:**

> What is the definition of center of rotation, and how to find it ?
>
> Secondly, any point on the body is fixed with respect to that body; on Earth, every point on the planet seems fixed, so do they mean *any* point on the rigid body by the second item ?

Comment: Related? [Which is axis of rotation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52408/which-is-the-axis-of-rotation?rq=1) and links therein.