# Calculating Rotations Associated with Circular Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

Suppose a motorcyclist is driving at constant speed along a circular track and, suppose further, that a local coordinate system is associated with the motorcycle, where

- $x$ is tangent to the circle and oriented in driving direction
- $z$ is orthogonal to the circle in the point of contact and tilted by an angle $\phi$ against the vertical
- $y$ is the cross procuct of $z$ and $x$, i.e. $y=z\wedge x$

> **Question:**
>
> how can I calculate the angular velocities around the individual axes?

Maybe the question is to simple, but I'm no physicist and perplexed by the peculiarities of mechanics.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0):

You construct a 3×3 rotation matrix from the components of the local axes as columns.

$$R = \left( 
\begin{array}{c|c|c} \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \end{array} \right) $$

I think for your case you have

$$R = \left( 
\begin{array}{c|c|c} 
  \cos \theta & -\sin\theta \cos\phi  & \sin\theta\sin\phi \\
  \sin\theta & \cos\theta \cos\phi &  -\cos\theta  \\
  0 & \sin\phi & \cos\phi
\end{array} \right) $$

where $\phi$ is the inclination angle, and $\theta$ is the angle along the arc of track.

Usually you construct this from a sequence of rotations

$$ R = \mathrm{RotZ}(\theta)\,\mathrm{RotX}(\phi) $$

This is then used to transform vectors from local coordinates to world coordinates.

Since you are given that in world coordinates $\boldsymbol{\omega} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ \dot{\theta}} $ (ground is along the *xy* plane), you can transform this to local coordinates with

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega}_{\rm local} = R^\top \boldsymbol{\omega} $$

But in the case where the tilt of the track changes, you can construct the rotational velocity vector, as a sequence of rotations

$$ \boldsymbol{\omega} = \hat{k} \dot{\theta} + \mathrm{RotZ}(\theta) \hat{\imath} \dot{\phi} = \pmatrix{ \dot{\phi} \cos\theta \\ \dot{\phi} \sin\theta \\ \dot{\theta} } $$

See [also related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/46000/392) post.