${}$ Angular velocity and acceleration
For a given rigid body, Can I get two different values of angular velocity about two different axes?
It is the case for angular acceleration, but is it so for angular velocity also?

Have you tried an example?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19201/2451

Yes, but it doesn't follow a fixed pattern or something.

Somewhere I read that angular acceleration about the circumference is half that about the centre fir a circle, but that is again not true for all the cases
