# Why are stationary rotations of a rigid body about the largest principal axis not Liapunov stable?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, stability

In Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics, 2nd ed.*, p. 145, he considers a rigid body with no external torque rotating about a fixed point O. He shows that the stationary solutions of the Euler equations (for the angular momentum vector in the body's co-rotating coordinate system) that correspond to the largest and smallest principal axis are Liapunov stable. This I understand. Then he claims that "stationary rotations of the body around the largest and smallest principal axes" are *not* Liapunov stable. This is left as an exercise to the reader, which I cannot solve.

Comment: Not OP's question but for the Dzhanibekov effect, the [tennis racquet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem), and the intermediate axis theorem, see e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17504/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34364/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67957/2451, and links therein.

Comment: Right. He probably meant not stable around the intermediate axis. You can try it with say a book, and it's proven in a number of class mechanics books.