# Why is this handle flipping back and forth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, stability

This gif of some kind of handle being spun in zero gravity has been doing the rounds:

[image: GREETINGS HUMAN]

Why is it flipping back and forth? It seems odd that it flips, then seems to rotate around one axis in a reasonably stable manner before suddenly flipping about entirely.

Comment: By "doing the rounds," OP means on [imgur](http://imgur.com/gallery/taJtuTe) and [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/gifs/comments/3du4ex/dancing_thandle_in_zero_gravity/). Related on Physics.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67957/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128471/, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131270

Comment: The rotation is not stable, if you let the hadle spin around this axis the slightest rotation around any other axis grows exponentially until it flips. You can observe this by throwing something like your smart phone into the air, there will be one axis that is unstable. Try it!