# What's the name for "middle" principal axis of inertia?

Tags: terminology, rigid-body-dynamics

See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67957/182971) for some context about the stability of rotation of a body around different axes.

I am now trying to say that the rotation around the middle axis is very unstable, **without using any formulae** (since I am writing something like an abstract). Here is what I mean by "middle axis":

> Let the moment of inertia around three principal axes be $I_1<I_2<I_3$. The axis with the moment of inertia $I_2$ is the "middle axis".

However, "middle axis" seems a vague phrase if it appears without some context, so can I really use it? **What should I say instead?** Is there any particular formal name for "middle axis"? I just feel that if I write "middle axis" without writing "the principal axis of inertia" first, people will struggle to see what I mean. But if I do include "the principal axis of inertia", it sounds redundant, since "middle axis" *is* certainly a principal axis.

Comment: Intermediate axis, as Wuberdall put it, or honestly, second axis of inertia would be understandable for me I think.

Answer (score 1):

It is often referred to as the intermediate axis.