# Why is it harder to flip my cell phone about one axis than the other two?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

There are three ways (three differenent axis about which) I can flip my cell phone - over the front (like a frontflip), about the center (like a disc of pizza dough being spun by a baker), and over sideways (like a dog rolling over, or like a pizza roller rotating as it rolls over the dough). Of all these ways to rotate, I've found that the first way, the frontflip-like rotation, is almost always unstable. It doesn't **only** rotate about that axis, even when I try really hard to make it do so. About the other two axes, however, it flips/rotates about **only** one axis, just as I intend it to.

[image]

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: Your battery is asymmetric about that axis. Is it anyway inspired from the Veritasium video?

Comment: see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34364

Comment: Could be due to it being a knock-off of Verizon ;)

Comment: Google 'tennis racket theorem' - covered well in Goldstein and Landau & Lifshitz classical mechanics texts (and elsewhere as well).

Comment: For the Dzhanibekov effect, the [tennis racquet theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_racket_theorem), and the intermediate axis theorem, see e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17504/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31475/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Sweet! @Cheeku what battery?