# A trio of spinning marbles

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, moment-of-inertia, inertia

My little brother showed me this devised act in which he stuck three marbles in a triangular pattern

[image]

When he spun any of those marbles, the triplet would first rotate normally,  but moments later, the system would be spinning on a single component. 
 I am suspecting that the toppling effects of friction are largely at play here, with rotational inertia balancing the two marbles atop the base one. Could someone please affirm my thinking, or is some other mechanism involved?

(This might be a pretty basic one, for some of the recipients, but hey, I am a student.)

Thanks.

Comment: Are the magnets glued together to form the shape you show? If so see [The secret behind the spinning, asymmetrically weighted, 2D disk-shaped top?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68223/the-secret-behind-the-spinning-asymmetrically-weighted-2d-disk-shaped-top)

Comment: I read the answer(without being able to fully comprehend it), and what bothers me, is why,  as mentioned in one of the answers " the disc will flip periodically  in the absence of friction ", when according to intuition,  it should behave like a gyroscope of sorts. I mean shouldn't it just slow down and fall back to the initial configuration once?