# Gyro mechanics with a coin

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

Take a coin and stick a little bit of chewing gum on it. Then give the coin some spin with your fingers. Why is the chewing gum moving to the top of the coin while it rotates? You could do also different setups (drilling hole for example) but always the heavier side moves up to the top.

Comment: I request you to please be a little more decent over here. I mean that sticking chewing gum, can you please replace it with something else and also write your thoughts on it (I mean why it happens).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/68223/2451