# Janibekov Effect

Tags: gravity, space

Recently I've learned about [Janibekov effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2o9eBl_Gzw), which looks like magic. What's the explanation behind it?

I remeber from school that if no force is applied then object should keep still or continue going as it did, what is the force in this case?

Comment: I think this question has answers: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17504/

Comment: I was looking for intuitive no-math answer. I guess there is no such one to this problem.

Comment: Yeah, not that I know of. I happened to have asked a similar question ages back, I got only mathematical answers, but they do make loads of sense once you look into it!

Comment: This seems to be a clear answer in plain English, but you have to be geometrically aware (scroll down to 1st answer, by Terry Tao): http://mathoverflow.net/q/81960/.  Basically, the instability is triggered by tiny inevitable perturbations in centrifugal force.